# .htaccess not excluding sub directory with rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm asking a question regarding my .htaccess. I'll quickly explain what i'm trying to accomplish and how it's not working.

I'm using the $_GET directory as a rule for the page.

i.e https://example.com/test?p=page1 = https://example.com/test/page1

I also have a directory called "account" inside this /test/ directory but when I try to access the page.

https://example.com/test/account it redirects me to https://example.com/test/account/?p=account
note (https://example.com/test/account/ works fine)

I've tried disabling it by following methods on other StackOverflow posts but none of this is working.

My rule is:

`RewriteRule    ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_\ ]+)/?$       index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]`

Is there any way I can configure this rule to exclude the word "account" and "admin" etc I've tried placing a .htaccess with the rewrite engine off but that doesn't work because the .htaccess thinks /account is a page rather than a directory.

I've tried other methods which stop directories with the same issue. It doesn't think /account is a directory. It thinks it's a page.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

add this line above to exclude requests with account or admin in them

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(account|admin)$ [NC]
```

put that above your current rule and it should exclude using the rule on requests including those terms.

here is what I use (have for ages), to do what you are wanting to do:

**I am pretty sure I could reduce this to a single set of expressions but I'm not that good.  Without the second I miss `domain.tld` and without the first I miss `fancy.domain.tld`

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.tld
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(actionspage|\/excludeddir\/|\/otherdir\/).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pre=%1&pos=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(actionspage|\/excludeddir\/|\/otherdir\/).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pre=0&pos=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}               !(account|admin)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_\ ]+)/?$       index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]` is still appending the `?p=account` onto the end of `/account/`

Comment: @ConorReid I added (edited) as example, a rendition of the code I use.